# Text fields not updating with user detail from VIEW button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

Im writing an application that connects to an API and allows users to do CRUD operations

In the Frontend.
I Have a button on each row in a table that is called 'View' once clicked, it should copy the info from the row that it was clicked on, into text fields for updating user details.

**Table with button**
[image: Table with buttons:]

**Update Filed after click**
[image: Update Field:]

I have a debugger under the `FillStudentInfo: function (studentId) {}` Method and when I debug i can see that the correct record is in the json response, but it doestn seem to add it to the text fields for some reason

**Debugger**
[image: Debugger]

As you can see, the update field is blank.

StudentSummary.js

```
var StudentSummaryManager = {
    GetAllStudents: function () {
        var obj = "";
        var serviceUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/student";
        AjaxManager.GetAPI(serviceUrl, onSuccess, onFailed);
        function onSuccess(jsonData) {
            obj = jsonData;   
        }
        function onFailed(error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
        return obj;
    },
    GetStudentById: function (studentId) {
        var obj = "";
        var serviceUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/student/" + studentId;
        AjaxManager.GetAPI(serviceUrl, onSuccess, onFailed);
        function onSuccess(jsonData) {
            obj = jsonData;
        }
        function onFailed(error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
        return obj;
    }
};
var StudentSummaryHelper = {
    InitStudentSummary: function () {
        StudentSummaryHelper.LoadStudent();
    },
    LoadStudent: function () {
        $("#Table tbody tr").remove();
        var studentList = StudentSummaryManager.GetAllStudents();
        $.each(studentList, function (i, item) {
            var rows = "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + item.StudentId + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.DateofEnrollment + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + item.Active + "</td>" +
                "<td><button class='btn btn-info' onClick='StudentSummaryHelper.FillStudentInfo(" + item.StudentId + ")'>View</button></td>" +
                "</tr>";
            $("#Table tbody").append(rows);
        });
    },
    FillStudentInfo: function (studentId) {
        debugger;
        var studInfo = StudentSummaryManager.GetStudentById(studentId);

        $("#btnSave").text("Update");
        $("#divDetails").show();
        $("#divSummary").hide();

        $("#txtStudentFirstName").val(studInfo.FirstName);
        $("#txtStudentLastName").val(studInfo.LastName);
        $("#txtStudentDate").val(studInfo.DateofEnrollment);
        $("#txtStudentActive").val(studInfo.Active);

    }
}
```

StudentSummary.cshtml

```
<script src="~/js/Student/StudentSummary.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h4>Summary of all students</h4>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="btnAdd">Add Student</button>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="Table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>StudentId</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>DateofEnrollment</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

StudentDetails.js

```
var StudentDetailsManager = {
    SaveStudent: function () {
        var obj = StudentDetailsHelper.CreateStudObj();
        var objStudent = JSON.stringify(obj);
        var serviceUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/student/AddStudent"
        AjaxManager.PostApi(serviceUrl, objStudent, onSuccess, onFailed)

        function onSuccess(jsonData) {
            if (jsonData.FirstName !== "") {
                $("#divDetails").hide();
                $("#divSummary").show();
                StudentSummaryHelper.LoadStudent();
                alert("Saved Successfully");
            }
            else {
                alert(jsonData);
            }
        }
        function onFailed(error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        }
    }
};
var StudentDetailsHelper = {
    InitStudentDetails: function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            $("btnSave").text("Save");
            $("#divDetails").show();
            $("#divSummary").hide();
            StudentDetailsHelper.ClearForms();
        });
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            StudentDetailsManager.SaveStudent();
        });
    },
    CreateStudObj: function () {
        debugger;
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.FirstName = $("#txtStudentFirstName").val();
        obj.LastName = $("#txtStudentLastName").val();
        obj.DateofEnrollment = $("#txtStudentDate").val();
        if ($("#txtStudentActive").is(":checked")) {
            obj.Active = "true"
        } else {
            obj.Active = "false"
            }
        return obj;
    },
    ClearForms() {
        $("#txtStudentFirstName").val("");
        $("#txtStudentLastName").val("");
        $("#txtStudentDate").val("");
        $("txtStudentActive").val(null);
    }
}
```

StudentDetails.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/js/Student/StudentDetails.js"></script>

<div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" id="hdnStudentId" value="0" />
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xl control-label" for="txtStudentFirstName">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStudentFirstName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xl control-label" for="txtStudentLastName">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtStudentLastName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xl control-label" for="txtStudentDate">Enrollment Date:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtStudentDate" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xl control-label" for="txtStudentActive">Active:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="txtStudentActive" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="spacer5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item centerAlign">
                    <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Save</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the javascript console and network tab. Are there any errors? Are there any extra requests that you aren't expecting?

Comment: Does this work if you run it directly in the console? `$("#txtStudentFirstName").val('foo');`

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, that changes the value of the field if i run it in console

Comment: @Crowcoder it seems as if my studInfo values are null (studInfo.FirstName, studInfo.LastName etc...) but i cant understand why, as can be seen in the image above, if I hover over studInfo in the debugger, it contains the JSON response with all the fields

Comment: Set the View buttons `type="button"` to make sure it is not posting back

Comment: Updated it to: ```<button class='btn btn-info' type=button onClick='StudentSummaryHelper.FillStudentInfo(" + item.StudentId + ")'>View</button> ``` Still no luck

Comment: Did you not put quotes around "button" or is that a comment typo?

Comment: Comment typo, but I found a fix...not sure why this solved the issue (welcome to my programming life) will post the answer now

Comment: @Jarrydvn dear may be its issue because of html loading after js, can you put your assign values js code into setTimeout for couple of seconds to debug the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason in the `FillStudentInfo: function (studentId) {}`
Method I needed to ad a `$.each` even though the response was only 1 Student.

Heres the fixed method that works:

```
    FillStudentInfo: function (studentId) {
    debugger;
    var studInfo = StudentSummaryManager.GetStudentById(studentId);
    $("#btnSave").text("Update");
    $("#divDetails").show();
    $("#divSummary").hide();
    $.each(studInfo, function (i, studInfo) {
        $("#txtStudentFirstName").val(studInfo.FirstName);
        $("#txtStudentLastName").val(studInfo.LastName);
        $("#txtStudentDate").val(studInfo.DateofEnrollment);
        $("#txtStudentActive").val(studInfo.Active);
    });

}
```